# Logstash / Elasticsearch: "Failed to install template" Got response code '400'

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

An error occurs while trying to apply `ngram` tokenizer through `logstash`.

```json
[ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Failed to install template {:message=>"Got response code '400' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'https://127.0.0.1:9200/_index_template/template-1'",
```

this is logstash output

```json
hosts => ["https://localhost:9200"]
            index => "test_index"
            document_id => "%{id}"
            user => "xxxxx"
            password => "xxxxxxxx"
            ssl_certificate_verification => false

            template => './templates/testTemplate.json'
            template_name=>"template-1"
            template_overwrite => true
```

and testTemplate.json

```json
{
    "template":"*",
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
          "analyzer": {
            "my_analyzer": {
              "tokenizers": ["my_tokenizer"]
            }
          },
          "tokenizer": {
            "my_tokenizer": {
              "type": "ngram",
              "min_gram": 1,
              "max_gram": 10,
              "token_chars": [
                "letter",
                "digit"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "name":{
                "type":"text",
                "fields":{
                    "ngram":{
                        "type":"text",
                        "analyzer":"my_analyzer"
                    }   
                }
                
            },
            "name2":{
                "type":"text",
                "fields":{
                    "ngram":{
                        "type":"text",
                        "analyzer":"my_analyzer"
                    }   
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using Logstash 8.x, which now uses the [new index template API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.8/index-templates.html), while your template has the [legacy format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.8/indices-templates-v1.html).

You simply need to change your `testTemplate.json` file to the new format:

```
{
 "index_patterns": ["test-*"],

 "priority": 100,
 "template": {
   "settings": {
  "max_ngram_diff": 9,
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "my_analyzer": {
        "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
      }
    },
    "tokenizer": {
      "my_tokenizer": {
        "type": "ngram",
        "min_gram": 1,
        "max_gram": 10,
        "token_chars": [
          "letter",
          "digit"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
},
"mappings": {
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "ngram": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        }
      }
    },
    "name2": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "ngram": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}
}

Comment: Thank you for answer.
I wrote the code according to your answer, but the same error message occurs..

Comment: Which version of ES and Logstash are you running?

Comment: Both versions are 8.8.1.

Comment: If you have a Kibana handy, can you go into Dev Tools and install it manually so we can see the underlying error? `PUT _index_template/template-1` and then add your template JSON on the next line

Comment: Yes, but we need to see the underlying error and doing it manually would help. Since you have `template_overwrite => true` the template will get overwritten on every run anyway, so no big deal

Comment: Oh I see the issue, `"tokenizers": ["my_tokenizer"]` should be `"tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"` since there can only be one single tokenizer. I've fixed my answer above, please try again

Comment: I apologize for the delay in responding.
1. the modified code also gives the same error.
2. when I put it, it says to change `index_patterns`, so I changed it to ["test-*"], and it says to set `max_ngram_diff`!

Comment: I changed the json in your answer, and this works fine. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Ok, Glad you figured it out ;-)